# Zend Framework 2 / Doctrine authentication from 2 entities

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 entities : `User` and `Member` to access different modules in my ZF2 application.

I have 2 different login forms to make the connection.

config of the `Member` dedicated module :

```
'doctrine'        =>
            [
                'authenticationservice' =>
                    [
                        'platform' => true,
                    ],
                'authenticationstorage' =>
                    [
                        'platform' => true,
                    ],
                'authenticationadapter' =>
                    [
                        'platform' => true
                    ],
                'authentication'        =>
                    [
                        'platform' =>
                            [
                                'storage'            => 'Platform_Auth',
                                'objectManager'      => EntityManager::class,
                                'identityClass'      => Member::class,
                                'identityProperty'   => 'login',
                                'credentialProperty' => 'password',
                                'credentialCallable' => function (Member $member, $password)
                                    {
                                        return ($member->getPassword() === md5($password));
                                    }
                            ],
                    ]
            ],
```

And `User` dedicated module

```
'doctrine'     =>
            [
                'authenticationservice' =>
                    [
                        'admin' => true,
                    ],
                'authenticationstorage' =>
                    [
                        'admin' => true,
                    ],
                'authenticationadapter' =>
                    [
                        'admin' => true
                    ],
                'authentication'        =>
                    [
                        'admin' =>
                            [
                                'storage'            => 'Admin_Auth',
                                'objectManager'      => EntityManager::class,
                                'identityClass'      => User::class,
                                'identityProperty'   => 'login',
                                'credentialProperty' => 'password',
                                'credentialCallable' => function (User $user, $password)
                                    {
                                        return ($user->getPassword() === md5($password));
                                    }
                            ]
                    ]
            ],
```

How can I use Doctrine authentication with 2 different configuration ?

Is there a way to achieve that ?

***edit***
I can use either one with a shared Authentication factory and extention (platform / admin) based on route ... But I don't know if it's a good idea ...

***edit2***

I have another error with the configured storage :

".... Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Admin_Auth in ..."

Any help would be very appreciated